# Unable to reach nested location directive for POST request caching

Tags: symfony, nginx, nginx-location

I'm configuring NginX to support caching of GET requests + a specific POST request.
I'm using the symfony framework and hence rewriting the URIs to something like: app.php/... .

To be able to separate handling of GET and POST caching I created some nested location directives.

```
fastcgi_cache_path /nginx_cache_path levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:10m max_size=1g inactive=120m loader_threshold=300 loader_files=150;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    root /path_to_web_server;

    location / {            

        # try to serve file directly. If not existing change to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;          

    }

    location ~ ^/images/.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ {

        root /path_to_images_folder;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {

        location ~ /post_request_path {

            fastcgi_cache_key "$request_uri|$request_body";
            fastcgi_cache_valid 5m;           
            fastcgi_cache_methods POST;

            fastcgi_cache one;
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503 http_404;

            fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
            add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

            internal;
        }

        location ~ / {

            fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;          
            fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;

            fastcgi_cache one;
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503 http_404;

            fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
            add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

            internal;
        }
}
```

My problem: the POST request is never cached. The "location ~ /post_request_path" is tested but never selected by NginX.

As per NginX debug log files:

```
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: "/"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: ~ "^/images/.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: ~ "^/app\.php(/|$)"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: ~ "\.php$"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 using configuration "/"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 internal redirect: "/app.php?"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: "/"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: ~ "^/images/.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: ~ "^/app\.php(/|$)"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: ~ "/post_request_path"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 test location: ~ "/"
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 using configuration "/"
```

I'm very suprised /post_request_path is never selected since I thought the NginX algorithm was selecting the first matching regular expression when several ones are matching the URI.

I guess I'm missing something big with nested location directives here...

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I was digging in the wrong direction. The problem wasn't coming from the nested location directives but from the **try_files** one.

The reason was under my eyes in the debug log:

```
2017/07/11 19:31:00 [debug] 13707#0: *8961 internal redirect: "/app.php?"
```

NginX was rewritting the URI to "/app.php?" instead of "/app.php/post_request_path"

And hence the "wrong" location directive route.

**Correction**

Change:

> try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;

to

> try_files $uri /app.php$uri;